# Why react hooks setState doesn't work here, but other method does?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

My goal is to take multiple ingredient items and combine them into a single item (a recipe). [Example of effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvQJO.jpg)

I have a total number of meals array that looks like this

```
numberOfMeals: Array(3)
0: {name: "Meal 1", meals: Array(3)}
1: {name: "Meal 2", meals: Array(0)}
2: {name: "Meal 3", meals: Array(0)}
```

I select **"Meal 1"** by setting **selectedMealNumber** state.

Once selected, I have a form component where I select the name and combine all 3 ingredient nutritional info into 1, by submitting this info:

```
selectedMealNumber.meals = [
      {
        product_name: "chicken and rice",
        ingredient_uid: uuidv4(),
        ingredients: selectedMealNumber.meals,
        nutrients: nutrients,
      },
    ];
```

Just to make clear the code above works perfectly and **numberOfMeals** array gets updated, I don't entirely understand how, but it works.

But I have read that I should be using setState instead, however when I use setState the **numberOfMeals** array doesn't get updated.

```
    setSelectedMealNumber({
      ...selectedMealNumber,
      meals: [
        {
          product_name: "chicken and rice",
          ingredients: selectedMealNumber.meals,
        },
      ],
    });
```

Please help me, why setState doesn't work in this instance, should I keep using other method?

Comment: When you say one way "works", what do you mean exactly? like when you console.log it's the correct data? or does doing `meals = ..` also somehow seem to update your html as well? (which it shouldn't unless you are making another `setState` call elsewhere

Comment: furthermore, by having an object reference itself this way,.. is this by design? so that you can do `setSelectedMealNumber.meals[0].indredients[0].ingredients` <-- etc

Comment: Yes, it does log correct data, you can see in the reference picture that everything renders as I want as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the way you set up the state is optimal. First of, if you want to access your meals in the state, it might be a bit easier to use an object here and assign an ID to each meal istead of accessing the array by index.

```
const [numberOfMeals, setNumberOfMeals] = useState({"Meal 1":{name: "Meal 1", meals: Array(3)},"Meal 2":{name: "Meal 2", meals: Array(0)},"Meal 3":{name: "Meal 3", meals: Array(0)}})
```

Now, it's quite easy to see what you are doing, when you are updating "Meal 1" instead of array[0], as it makes things a bit more concrete. Side note: You might also want to rethink your variable name "numberOfMeals". Is the variable really storing a number?

I didn't change it for the sake of clarity.

Now you have to find the right spot to update the meals array, as it is not accessible on the top level, as you were trying to do it in your example.

```
setNumberOfMeals({...numberOfMeals, "Meal 1":{...numberOfMeals["Meal 1"], meals:[newMeal]}})
```

In order to do so, you need to "spread" your way all the way down until you reach the meals-key.

More explicitly: Within numberOfMeals, we would like to adjust the object at key "Meal 1". Within "Meal 1", we are looking for the meals-key and adjust the array accordingly.